# How to access git centralized scripts from build and release steps (VSTFS 2018)

Tags: git, tfs, scripting

I have opend the thread in the link below in order to know how to access a centralized set of powershell scripts during the build and release process. The solution suggested in this link worked for the build process since the GetSources step downloads the scripts from the git repository and stores them in the agent working directory. But when I run the release process the scripts are not there anymore since the working directory for the release process is different from the build one. Moreover, the release agent could be different from the build one. Is there a way to download scripts in a place where both, build and release could access them?

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/f3ed703b-cb6c-47f9-80aa-9883a4905caa/how-to-access-centralized-script-from-buildrelease-step-vstfs-2018?forum=visualstudiogeneral

Thanks in advance,
Paola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general trick is to create a build definition that publishes the latest scripts as an artifact. Then add that build as a artifact to the release pipeline.

Comment: That´s right, the only way I realized I can get this is by publishing the Scripts directory as part of the build artifacts and then let the release process access them through $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\$(Build.DefinitionName)\Scripts path.